# Javascript uploads empty audio in Chrome on Mac

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome, upload

This is my JS code for recording and uploading:

```js
async function startRecording() {
    try {
        stopAudio();
        mediaStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
        mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStream);

        mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
            if (event.data.size > 0) {
                recordedChunks.push(event.data);
            }
        };

        mediaRecorder.onstop = () => {
            const blob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: 'audio/mp3' });
            recordedChunks = [];
            console.log('Blob created:', blob);
            uploadAudio(blob);
        };

        mediaRecorder.start();
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error starting recording:', error);
    }
}


function stopRecording() {
    if (mediaRecorder) {
        mediaRecorder.stop();
    }
    if (mediaStream) {
        mediaStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    }
}


async function uploadAudio(blob) {
    try {
        console.log('Uploading recording...');
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('file', blob, 'recording.mp3');
        console.log('FormData created:', formData, 'Blob size:', blob.size);
        for (let [key, value] of formData.entries()) {
            console.log(key, value);
        }

        const response = await fetch(upload_endpoint, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: formData,
        });
        console.log(response);
        if (response.ok) {
            console.log('Audio uploaded successfully');
        } else {
            console.error('Error uploading audio:', response.statusText);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading audio:', error);
    }
}
```

When I run `startRecording()` and then `stopRecording()` on Chrome, the result on the server (running on `localhost:5000` using Flask) is an empty file. Doing the same thing with Safari (I'm running on Mac) works perfectly.

What am I missing?